# ColdFusion Initializing a Java object method that requires an external config file

Tags: java, coldfusion, constructor, init, createobject

I've been banging my head on this for a while, can't seem to find any decent answers or explanations for these errors. I am using a 3rd party JAR "PropHandler.jar"
I am trying to call the getMessageList method, it accepts 3 args and requires a config file.

```
<cfset configFile = 'C:\data\getMsgListCONFIG.xml'>
<cfset Obj = createObject("java","client.PropHandler") />
<cfdump var="#Obj#">
```

All good here, my dump returns a list of methods. Now, I need to get my config file to the method and pass in my args, no love here, I have tried this:

```
<cfset x = Obj.getMessageList.init(configFile)>
```

And

```
<cfset x = Obj.getMessageList().init(configFile)>
```

And

```
<cfset x = Obj.getMessageList('identifier', 'greaterthan', '2012-05-18T12:00:00-04:00').init(configFile)>
```

And even tried initializing via the creation of the object:

```
<cfset Obj = createObject("java","client.PropHandler").getMessageList('identifier', 'greaterthan', '2012-05-18T12:00:00-04:00').init(configFile)>
```

All Return the same error:

> **Object Instantiation Exception**
>
> An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class
>   must not be an interface or an abstract class. If the class has a
>   constructor that accepts an argument, you must call the constructor
>   explicitly using the init(args) method. Error : client.PropertyHandler

When I don't send the 3 args I get a method not found error, if I don't send the init I get the same error.

So, I do not have a lot of experience with JAVA and I do not understand the error message. I can use the JAR fine when calling from a command line, or even when executing with a BAT file, but when I do that I can't get the XML SOAP array returned to me...

**From the Java Doc:**

**PropertyHandler**

> `public PropertyHandler(java.lang.String propFile)
>                         throws java.lang.Exception`
>
> Uses a Property File to set up all program variables. This Property
>   File refers to a second  Property File that identifies user Id and
>   security file data.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - `propFile` -  XML file of Properties
>
> **Throws:**
>
> - `java.lang.Exception`

**getMessageList**

> ```
> public services.[...].GetResponseTypeDef getMessageList(java.lang.String par1,
>                   java.lang.String comp_Op1,
>                   java.lang.String parValue1 )
> ```
>
> Overrides X_Properties to returns a list of metadata about each
>   message that meets the query defined by the function parameters.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - `par1` - One of Parameter enum
> - `comp_Op1` - One of CompOp enum
> - `parValue1` - a value for comparison
>
> **Returns:**
>
> metadata message list meeting query criteria Returns null if an
>   exception is encountered instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Try calling init() on the Java object, then call the method with its arguments. Obj.init(...).getMessageList(...)

Comment: Obj.init(configfile).getMessageList('identifier', 'greaterthan', '2012-05-18T12:00:00-04:00')   

Same Error: Object Instantiation Exception.

An exception occurred when instantiating a Java object. The class must not be an interface or an abstract class. Error: ''.

Comment: That is just a boilerplate message you get with java objects, Can you update your question to include the *full* stack trace? (That is where the real error message lies). Also, what is the actual value of `#configFile#`?

Comment: Never mind about the file path. I see it was just hidden due to the tags.

Comment: @Leigh You Rock. looking in the stack trace I found that the config file had a relative path to another config file in it. Changing the ../path to a C:\REAL_PATH fixed the error! THANKS!

Comment: Great!  You should write it up as an answer (and include a snippet of the stack trace), so it is easier to find.

Comment: Yes, if you could please phrase your answer as an answer, instead of a comment, then we can vote up the solution for future searches.

Comment: Just an FYI about java objects. Technically you only need to invoke `init(..)` explicitly when either a) the class lacks a *public* no-arg constructor or b) you specifically want to pass in arguments (like this case). The reason is when you call a method CF checks to see if the object was instantiated already. If not, it attempts to do it for you, by calling the class' no-arg constructor ie `public SomeClass() {...`. So again, you do not *always* need to call `init()` explicitly. That said, calling it explicitly is a good practice IMO. It makes for clearer code and avoids inadvertent errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the call works as:

```
<cfset Obj = createObject("java","client.PropHandler") />   
<cfset Meth = Obj.init(argfile).getMessageList(arg1,arg2,arg3)>
```

The `argfile` variable is the path to an XML config file, and it also referenced another config file using a relative path. I found this error from the stack trace (below) once the path was changed to absolute inside `argfile` the error was resolved.

> Stack Trace at
>   cf_getMsgs2ecfm497532872.runPage(E:\Inetpub\wwwroot_getMsgs.cfm:24) 
>   at
>   cf_getMsgs2ecfm497532872.runPage(E:\Inetpub\wwwroot_getMsgs.cfm:24)
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.CreateObject(JavaProxy.java:156)
>     at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.invoke(JavaProxy.java:63)  at
>   coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2272)     at
>   cf_getMsgs2ecfm497532872.runPage(E:\Inetpub\wwwroot_getMsgs.cfm:24)
>     at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)  at
>   coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:370)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:279)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
>     at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)  at
>   coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
>     at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)    at
>   coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
>     at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:175)   at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>     at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)   at
>   coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>     at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>     at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)   at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)    at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)   at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)    at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
>     at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66) Caused by:
>   **java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\data\APIproperties.xml (The system
>   cannot find the path specified)**     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:66)   at
>   client.PropertyHandler.(PropertyHandler.java:133)

Thanks @Leigh and @imthepitts